# Mysql Query : between a number range when numbers have hyphens

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like following, and I am trying to get all the values where `reg_number` is in between `01-01-02-000002` AND `01-01-02-000004`

```
id  name               reg_number
1   Charlie Sheen      01-01-02-000001
2.  John Cryer         01-01-02-000002
3.  Roger Federar      02-02-02-000001
4.  Jason Stathum      01-01-02-000003
5.  Robert De Niro     01-01-02-000004
```

I have tried the following code to achieve this but its not working. Is it because of the hyphens I have in `reg_number`? If it is could you please tell me the solution to this problem ?
Thanks :)

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE reg_number >='01-01-02-000002' AND reg_number <= '01-01-02-000004'
```

Comment: It's probably because you don't *have* numbers.

Comment: What result are you expecting, and what do you get? Looks to me like it should return John Cryer, Jason Stathum, and Robert De Niro. BTW, you can use `a BETWEEN min AND max` instead of `a >= min AND a <= max`.

Comment: Your query looks right, I don't see any issue or problem with anything you've included here. You say "it's not working", but fail to indicate  in what way... MySQL exception or an unexpected resultset.

Comment: I am sorry, my code was not returning any value so I thought that I had some problems in my code, but I don't know why.. when I used Gordon Linoff's code it just worked for me, but interestingly his code is just as same as mine. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just built this on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76dc9/1/0) and it works.

The code is:

```
create table mytable (
      id int,
      name varchar(255),
      reg_number varchar(255)
  );

insert into mytable
    select 1, 'Charlie Sheen', '01-01-02-000001' union all
    select 2, 'John Cryer', '01-01-02-000002' union all
    select 3, 'Roger Federar', '02-02-02-000001' union all
    select 4, 'Jason Stathum', '01-01-02-000003' union all
    select 5, 'Robert De Niro', '01-01-02-000004'
```

and then your query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry, my code was not returning any value so I thought that I had some problems in my code, but I don't know how.. when I used your code it just worked for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @black_belt . . . One of the reasons stack overflow is here is because it can be really useful to have someone else look at a problem.  Sometimes the simplest of issues can waste a lot of time, particularly when you try to solve it alone.

Answer (score 1):

How is the code not working? Which result do you get? What works for me is:

```
set @reg_number = '01-01-02-000003'; 
select @reg_number >='01-01-02-000002' AND @reg_number <= '01-01-02-000004';
```

which results to true.